# how to config webpack loader exclude path that contains 'fonts'

Tags: webpack

```
{   test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/, 
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&name=/Presentation/_dist/images/[name].[ext]', 
    exclude: path.resolve(__dirname, "MY-FONTS-FOLDER")
}
```

Some fonts file name are ended with SVG, so I'd like to exclude any files that its path contains 'fonts', e.g: 'C:\project\app\module\fonts', 'C:\project\app\module2\fonts'.

The problem is the program is loader test condition seems only apply to file name, or specific path, but how can I test path string contain any 'fonts' string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a regular expression inside `exclude` that selects all font folders. For example:

```
{   
    test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/, 
    loader: 'url?limit=10000&name=/Presentation/_dist/images/[name].[ext]', 
    exclude: /(\/fonts)/
}
```

Comment: yes, it looks good! I think I can build on top of your idea. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use it:

```
{   
   test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg)$/, 
   loader: 'url?limit=10000&name=/Presentation/_dist/images/[name].[ext]', 
   exclude: /MY-FONTS-FOLDER/
}
```

Comment: In my project, the fonts folder is sub folder in different module folders, e.g: /module1/fonts, /module2/fonts, ... Your exclude only exclude one folder. Is there a way to test the existence of 'fonts' word in the file path?